# May you download images dropped in your app as mime type uri-list?

Tags: drag-and-drop

If your app supports drag and drop and receives a drop with mime type subtype uri-list, is it possible to look for image-like suffixes in the uri's (e.g. .jpg) and then download the images?  For example if your app is a drawing program?

Answer (score 0):

Outline of solution in Qt:

Get a QMimeData in an event handled by dropEvent() handler.
Get a uri-list from the mimeData if it hasFormat('uri-list').
Iterate over the strings of the uri-list until you find one that satisfies:

Create a QUrl from the string.
Use QMimeDatabase.mimetypeForUrl(string) to get a QMimeType.
Is the mime type one that your app supports?

Use QNetworkAccessManager to download the url (in the background, with signals for completion.)  Meanwhile, your app might display a placeholder or a busy cursor.  It doesn't matter if the url is to a local file, the mechanism will still 'download' the url (just more quickly.)

Your app prioritizes mimetypes in a mimedata, and only looks at the uri-list mime type (a reference, or indirection) if a mime type format is not directly (embedded) in the mime data.

The whole process of drag and drop is highly dependent on platform and the pair of sending and receiving apps.  One sending app may choose to embed a mime type while another may choose to send a url in a uri-list (url pointing to data whose content has the mime type, and url whose suffix indicates a mime type.)  On a platform, most receiving apps may prefer a certain mime type (e.g. image/jpeg) and not accept similar mime types (e.g. image/png.)